# Multiple Selects in for DataTable in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an interactive visualisation / RShiny app which allows me to show a datatable using two different selectors but I can only get one to work so far. Below is the code for the one selector.

```
# Create data table
  output$reviewstable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    reviews_sample <- reviews %>%
      sample_n(input$n) %>%
      select(Hotel_Address:Reviewer_Score, days_since_review:lng)

    DT::datatable(data = reviews_sample,
                  options = list(pageLength = 10), 
                  rownames = FALSE)
```

Now I want to add another with the following code:

```
# req(input$Hotel_Name)
# reviews_from_selected_hotel <- reviews %>%
#   filter(Hotel_Name %in% input$Hotel_Name) %>%
#   select(Hotel_Address:Reviewer_Score, days_since_review:lng)
```

I've done several attempts to merge the two so that the app takes both inputs (if selected) into account when displaying the data table. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider row binding the two data frames:

```
rbind(reviews %>%
         sample_n(input$n) %>%
         select(Hotel_Address:Reviewer_Score, days_since_review:lng)
      ,
      reviews %>%
         filter(Hotel_Name %in% input$Hotel_Name) %>%
         select(Hotel_Address:Reviewer_Score, days_since_review:lng)
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create and render two outputs separately, but make them appear on same panel so that they are side by side

Comment: I could probably create two separate outputs/data tables, yes, but my goal is to create one output based on several selections.

For example, one selector by which I can choose a $Hotel_Name, and a $Review_Date.

Comment: Just like grid.arrange, grid.table might work if there is something like that. I see grid.table mentioned in other threads you can check out. That may be the solution